# What are the differences between these two methods of Semi-logarithmic plotting?

Tags: regression, correlation, statistical-significance, data-transformation

I have my measurement data in (x, y). I am trying to plot a semi-logarithmic plot of y versus log (x). It looks like that there are two ways to plot such a graph.

1. Transform the values of x to log (x) for all values of x. Then, I could plot (log x, y) similar to that of plotting (x, y).
2. Arrange y in log scale (example, for a base of 10, arrange x axis by a decade), and plot the data set exactly like I would plot (x, y) in this logarithmic scale. In other words, I do not need to compute logarithmic values of x. Instead, I could simply rearrange x axis in logarithmic scale and then plot (x, y).

Here are my two questions:

1. Are both the options discussed above the same thing in terms of data representation? If both methods of plotting are the same, I would assume the slope of data set would be the same using both the methods.
2. I would like to show that my variable in y is linear with log of the variable in x axis. In order to do so, I plotted the (x, y) data set using the second method of plotting discussed above and did a linear fit. I got a R2 value close to 0.95. Please provide  your suggestions about the validity of this method.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between taking logs of the x-values and plotting the x-values on
paper with a log-x scale lies in the *labeling* of the horizontal axis.

In the former case, the x-axis
has labels according to the values of $\log(x).$ In the latter case, the (distorted) x-axis has
labels according to the values of $x$.

In the plots below, the first plots the data without any attention to logs.
In the second, the x-axis has values of $\log(x).$ In the third, the $x$-values
are plotted on a log scale. The second and third plots both appear to be roughly linear.

If the scales are appropriate, the slopes will *appear* to be the same.
Numerically, they will not be the same because different numbers are used. In
the plot at right, numerically the plot is not really a line, but distorted
to look as if it were a line by the log scale on the horizonal axis.

This example uses R and 'logs' are natural logarithms, 
not logs-base-10.

[image]

R code for the three plots:

```
set.seed(1216)
x0 = rnorm(50, 10, 2);  x = exp(x0)
y = x0 + runif(50, 0, .5)
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
  plot(x, y)
  plot(log(x), y);  plot(x, y, log="x")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Data description:

```
summary(x)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
   785.3   8664.6  30791.7 106720.1 100116.2 752057.6 
summary(log(x))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  6.666   9.067  10.334  10.328  11.514  13.531 

cor(x, y);  cor(log(x), y)  # Pearson correlations
[1] 0.7880628
[1] 0.9958471
cor(x, y, method="spearman");  cor(log(x),y, method="spearman")
[1] 0.9937575
[1] 0.9937575
```